# Prevent Excel hyperlink spaces from being converted to %20

Tags: excel, hyperlink

How does one prevent Excel from converting spaces in hyperlinks to "%20" when linking to local file-system files ?

**As an example of the problem; If I input the following into a hyperlink:**

'\Process Combination Reports\Users_ProcessCombination_493_495.xlsx'

**Excel will convert the hyperlink to:**

'\Process%20Combination%20Reports\Users_ProcessCombination_493_495.xlsx'

**Updates.**

1. The issue happens with relative hyperlinks (i.e ../mydir1/file 1.xslx) to other files. Absolute links appear to work.

Comment: ..............Encase the text in double-quotes.........

Comment: My Excel 2010 doesn't do that. Are you talking about Insert Hyperlink or the HYPERLINK worksheet function?

Comment: Gary, I tried encasing with double quotes without luck.
Dick, the issue occurs on Excel's "Insert Hyperlink" feature.

Comment: Kusleika, I tested absolute hyperlinks to files and they maintain the spacing. The relative ones fail with spaces replaced by %20. Post updated.

Answer (score 1):

Morning TheLegendaryCopyCoder.

Assuming you've probably fixed this by now, but I use the following code to fix post Hyperlink creation.

```
Sub links_fix()

Dim hlink    As Hyperlink
Dim rw1, rw2 As Integer

    sh02.Select

    rw1 = 3
    rw2 = sh02.Cells(sh02.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        Do Until rw1 > rw2
        
            For Each hlink In sh02.Cells(rw1, 6).Hyperlinks
                hlink.TextToDisplay = Replace(hlink.TextToDisplay, "%20", "_")
            Next hlink

            rw1 = rw1 + 1

        Loop

End Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Additional note. For the code to work, You need to run it separate to the code that creates the hyperlinks. e.g. I call the code on the worksheet (with the hyperlinks) activate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).